# push many arrays in one unique multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

From a specific query I recover a multi-dimensional array containing for example properties of User class.

The number of Users entries (number of User in Users array query result) is duynamic. For a specific script, I need to recover specific values of this array concerning User. For example **email, username, phone number** etc ...
But I don't need to recover all values.

So following the specifications, I create a foreach loop like this:

```
$finalArray = array(); // my final multi array containing all specific User data I sortin the foreach loop
$userArray = array(); // define an empty array to push unique user data I need
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $userArray['email'] = $user->getEmail();
    $userArray['username'] = $user->getUserName();
    /*
     * etc ...
     *
     **/
}
```

Now I need to put all `$userArray` into my `$finalArray`, but `$finalArray` has to be a multidiemensionnal array like this:

```
var-dump($finalArray);

/** have to return a multi dim array like this **/

array (size=2)
    0 => /** user one **/
        array (size=5)
            0 => string 'user1 email' 
            1 => string 'user1 username' 
    1 => /** user 2 **/
        array (size=5)
            0 => string 'user2 email' 
            1 => string 'user2 username' 
    2 => /** user 3 **/
        array (size=5)
            0 => string 'user3 email' 
            1 => string 'user3 username' 
    3 => /** user 4
            etc ...
    **/
```

How can I proceed to create this array in this format containing all `$userArray` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create the `$userArray` you just need to add that to `$fianlArray` as new entry like this:

```
$finalArray = array(); // my final multi array containing all specific User data I sortin the foreach loop

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $userArray = array(); // define an empty array to push unique user data I need
    $userArray['email'] = $user->getEmail();
    $userArray['username'] = $user->getUserName();
    /*
     * etc ...
     *
     **/

     //Add userArray as a new entry in finalArray.
     $finalArray[] = $userArray;
}
```

Comment: @ChetanAmeta Yes, it's better to reset it every time to empty array in case the fields are different from user to user. I moved in the loop. Thanks

Comment: it seems the answer so simple as my question is stupid, a rookie question by the way (sorry), I have test a lot of things, but I don't think about add this line into the foreach loop ! Thank you, you save my day, and I realize I need to be more concentrated when I wrote some code.

Answer (score 3):

It would be enough to use a single array `$finalArray` to get the needed multidimensional array:

```
$finalArray = [];
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $finalArray[] = ['email' => $user->getEmail(), 'username' => $user->getUserName()];
    /**
     * etc ...
    **/
}
```

Comment: your answer is a good one. However, I validated the first written response, do not take it personally, it's just because another stack user was faster than you. But thank you to take the time to write a post and help me to realize that I need to concentrate myself because this question was really a rookie one.

Comment: @french_dev, that's OK